What should I do to use a QTreeView child to select a subset of data in a model to show it in a QTableView?
Here I'm trying to create an Qt model/view that shows different subsets of data in a table view from a model depending of the child selected/clicked in the QTreeView, but I'm new at this and the examples I'm finding does not do anything close to this. Also I'm not finding the Qt Documentation to be really clear about how to do it either.

I stored the data in a QMap just as an example data and used it to fill the model of the table, but what should I do to make the tree and the table to work together? How can I tell the model to show only the data of the child I clicked in the tree view? I read something about proxies but I'm not sure if it applies for this case. Please help me with your suggestions.
At the time I'm using a model for the tree view and another model for the table view, that's why I have two QMaps.
QMap<QString,QList<QString>> namesMap;
namesMap = {{"Parent #1", {"Child 1-1", "Child 1-2", "Child 1-3"}},
            {"Parent #2", {"Child 2-1", "Child 2-2"}},
            {"Parent #3", {"Child 3-1"}}};

QMap<QString,QList<QList<QString>>> dataMap;
dataMap = {{"Child 1-1", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "1-1"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}},
           {"Child 1-2", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "1-2"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}},
           {"Child 1-3", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "1-3"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}},
           {"Child 2-1", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "2-1"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}},
           {"Child 2-2", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "2-2"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}},
           {"Child 3-1", {{"Name 1", "00000000000000", "3-1"},{"Name 2", "00000000000000", ""}}}};

This is how I set the model I used to work with the tableview, and the model for the treeview:
tableModel = new QStandardItemModel(3,3,this);

QMap<QString,QList<QList<QString>>>::iterator itr;
for (itr = dataMap.begin(); itr != dataMap.end(); ++itr)
{
    int row = 0;
    // iterating through the Qlist
    QListIterator<QList<QString>> i(itr.value());
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        QList list = i.next();
        for (int col = 0; col < list.size(); ++col)
        {
            QModelIndex index = tableModel->index(row, col, QModelIndex());
            tableModel->setData(index, list.at(col));
        }
        ++row;
    }
}

treeModel = new QStandardItemModel(this);

QStandardItem *root = treeModel->invisibleRootItem();
QList<QStandardItem*> rowItems;

QMap<QString,QList<QString>>::iterator iter;
for (iter = namesMap.begin(); iter != namesMap.end(); ++iter)
{
    QString parentName = QString(iter.key());
    QStandardItem *parent = new QStandardItem(parentName);
    parent->setEditable(false);
    rowItems << parent;
    root->appendRow(rowItems);
    rowItems.clear();

    QListIterator<QString> i(iter.value());
    while (i.hasNext())
    {
        QString childName = QString(i.next());
        QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(childName);
        item->setEditable(false);
        rowItems << item;
        parent->appendRow(rowItems);
        rowItems.clear();
    }
}

treeView = new QTreeView(this);
treeView->setModel(treeModel);

dataTable = new QTableView(this);
dataTable->setModel(tableModel);


Are you sure you really need two models and mappings? Because you could just use one, with each "table" as actual child of the corresponding "leaf", then use a specialized proxy model that only shows the first two level of the tree model, and then use setRootIndex() on the table view with the selected index of the tree view.

What you should be using is a QSortFilterProxyModel.
See the example in the Qt Documentation.
You connect your view with your QSortFilterProxyModel derived class and put in the current model as backend into the QSortFilterProxyModel. So you just extend your current code, you do not have to rewrite everything.
